# Python's PIL crop problem: color of cropped image screwed

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, python-imaging-library, crop

I have a probably very basic problem with PIL's crop function: The cropped image's colors are totally screwed. Here's the code:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> img = Image.open('football.jpg')
>>> img
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile instance at 0x00
>>> img.format
'JPEG'
>>> img.mode
'RGB'
>>> box = (120,190,400,415)
>>> area = img.crop(box)
>>> area
<PIL.Image._ImageCrop instance at 0x00D56328>
>>> area.format
>>> area.mode
'RGB'
>>> output = open('cropped_football.jpg', 'w')
>>> area.save(output)
>>> output.close()
```

The original image: [image]

[and the output](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_6sm8225Z3w8/SgG0AWKPUaI/AAAAAAAAAjw/SWP360wFo1M/cropped_football.jpg).

As you can see, the output's colors are totally messed up...

Thanks in advance for any help!

-Hoff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`output` should be a file name, not a handler.

Comment: Well, it can be a file, but it needs to be opened in binary mode. Still, better to have PIL handle that when it's convenient.

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
output = open('cropped_football.jpg', 'w')
area.save(output)
output.close()
```

just do

```
area.save('cropped_football.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the call to `save` actually produced output, I have to assume that PIL is able to use either a filename or an open file interchangeably. The problem is in the file mode, which by default will try to convert based on text conventions - a '\n' will be replaced by '\r\n' on Windows. You need to open the file in binary mode:

```
output = open('cropped_football.jpg', 'wb')
```

P.S. I tested this and it works:

[image]